# drawing Chart using .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net

I want to draw a graph/chart in runtime in my windows desktop application. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and C#.NET 3.5.

I know about Chart control in .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010, but didn't find any similar control in Visual Studio 2008.

is there any way to plot a graph using .NET 3.5 in VS2008?

Comment: Do you need winforms or web components?

Comment: @Dos095-russ...I need Windows Forms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend you [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html), it is free and opensource. And [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET) you can find an article about it.

Anyway, there are plenty of commercial components with charting functionality on [ComponentSource](http://www.componentsource.com/relevance/net-winform-controls/index.html?q=chart).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/10/free-winform-and-aspnet-chart-controls.html) is a good chart controls for WinForms and ASP.Net from Microsoft, moreover there are good examples how to use these controls